# Androids MediaPlayer onErrorListener MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED make problems

Tags: android, error-handling, media-player, android-videoview

I have the following code to close the current Activity.

```
if(what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED){
    DialogFragment videoNotAvailable = new VideoNotAvailableDialogFragment();
    videoNotAvailable.show(getFragmentManager(), "NoVideo");
}
```

But the result of this code is a black screen without anything else. The dialog is not shown. Can anyone help? Maybe I did not understand the meaning of this statement (MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED)...?

additional added:
the VideoNotAvailableDialog include this and is working in another part:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.videoNotAvailablePart1))
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.videoNotAvailableAccept_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User accepts the message
                    ((LiveStreamActivity) getActivity()).finish();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. After some minutes, a video played from internal/external memory would stop playing and I got black screen but I added a progress dialog, "Error Finding video!" whenever I got an exception trying to playback the video. Add this piece of code to be called whenever an error occurs:

```
 myVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("MainActivity","WHAT: "+ what + " EXTRA: "+extra);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Error: "+what);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

you will have to `reset()` the media player, and instantiate a new one depending on what error number you get. See Android documentation on their [website](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED).